# Previous row value being written

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I am trying to only add values from rows where a checkbox named "Addbox" is true, the below code identifies when a checkbox is ticked and only adds those items to the users wishlist. However it adds them with the previous row's quantity regardless of if the checkbox is true or false.

Checkbox code is

```
"input type = 'checkbox' name='Addbox[]' value='" . $row['Item_ID'] . "'
```

If statement code is

```
if (isset($_POST['Add'])) {

  if(isset ($_POST['Addbox'])){

    //counts the size of the array addbox[] so the for loop has an end.
    $count = count($_POST['Addbox']);

    //starts the sql query string to added to inside the for loop.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`User_ID`,`Product_ID`,`Quantity`) VALUES ";

    //initiate for loop... do this until every row in the array has been looked at essentially.
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        //get the values of this row.
        $item = $_POST['Addbox'][$i];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];

        // Add the end of the sql string for each of the loops.
        $sql .= "($userid, $item, $quantity)";

        //This check is it is the last of the row in the array. If it isnt add a comma and space ready for the next row.
        if($i !== $count-1){
            $sql .= ", ";
        }
    }

    mysql_query($sql);
    // var_dump($sql)
}
```

Comment: I'd be more worried about the gaping [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes in your code... But remember that checkboxes which are NOT checked off in a form are **NOT** submitted, so the only checkboxes you receive are the selected ones.

Comment: mysql_ ... here we go again. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: This is part of a university degree so MySQL is my only choice as it is part of the criteria.. If the checkboxes are not submitted how am I to stop the $quantity variable being written to each and every time rather than only when the checkboxes are checked off? I have tried a "Please Select" option but with it being an array it just breaks the SQL statement all together.

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);` and see what the values you have are.  How is this a SQL issue?  It looks like an HTML issue or a logical issue.

Comment: @RickyWelch if you read the link that Arthur gave you, that MySQL API is now deprecated and has been declared as going deprecated for a while.  There are other MySQL APIs, such as mysqli and PDO.  Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.api.choosing.html .  If you are being tought to use the old `mysql_` methods, your university is doing you a disservice.

Comment: Show your HTML, the problem is probably with the way you have the checkboxes named.

Comment: Output of print_r is as expected Array
(
    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 7
        )

    [Addbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 39
        )

    [additem] => Add selected to Wishlist
)

Comment: You can solve the checkbox problem by putting this before it:

Comment: I have updated the question with checkbox code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST['Addbox'] as $key=>$itemId){
    //get the values of this row.
    $item = $_POST['Addbox'][$key];
    $quantity = if (!empty($_POST['quantity'][$key])) $_POST['quantity'][$key]; else 0;
    // Could also be written as $quantity = !empty($_POST['quantity'][$key]) ? $_POST['quantity'][$key] : 0;

    // Add the end of the sql string for each of the loops.
    $sql .= "($userid, $item, $quantity)";
}
```

For the HTML, try this:

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='Addbox[{$row['Item_ID']}]' value='{$row['Item_ID']}' />"
```

This will iterate through every item in the array `$_POST['Addbox']` and give you its `$key` in the array and the item's `$itemId`, or value (which you made the Item ID).  It will then append to your SQL string.

**Warning:** You usually want to prevent against malicious clients with sanity and validity checks.  There are some good answers already on StackOverflow for preventing SQL injection.  You also need to check for empty, invalid characters, overflowing numbers, etc.  This snippet, as it stands now is vulnerable and can cause problems if `$key` or `$itemId` contain unintended values (including being not set or empty).

More information on `foreach()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I am afraid that didn't solve the issue, Print_r output is >Array
(
    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 9
        )

    [Addbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 39
        )

    [additem] => Add selected to Wishlist. As before it write the first two values of quantity to the selected items.

Comment: Your problem is you are filling out quantity fields for an item that is not checked.  Try changing your HTML to contain `name='Addbox[0]'`, `name='quantity[0]'`, incrementing 0 for each successive item.  Then your keys for a given item will match for your checkbox and item quantity. (`Addbox[1]` will correspond to `quantity[1]`, if both are set).

Otherwise, `Addbox[0]` could correspond to your fifth textbox if that is the first one that is set (first through fourth textboxes are empty).

Comment: Changed the html so that select name=quantity[0] and input type=checkbox name addbox[0] and now my output from print_r after checking two boxes is Array
(
    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [Addbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39
        )

    [additem] => Add selected to Wishlist